# Webcam frame splitter

Tags: beginner, go, server, raspberry-pi, video

I wrote a camera streaming app for pizero.

Since the pizero is too weak to do any video encoding  I am using it to just capture usb webcam frames (mjpeg format) and forward them over udp to a powerful pc that does the video encoding.

When the light conditions are low there is a lot of noise introduced to the frames and they grow in size, overflowing the udp write size limit.

To tackle the issue I wrote a func that splits the frame in parts and forwards the pieces to the encoder.

What I am looking for in this review is the following:

Performance - App runs on pizero where resources are limited. I am using buffered channels and I am not sure if I implemented them correctly.

Best practices

Hidden pitfalls - If any, point out if I shot myself in the foot.

Code contains the whole camera implementation plus the server side.

Please review both.

My programming level is beginner. This is my first project.

Camera:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "net"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

const (
    FFMPEG_ENCODER = "192.168.178.200:8000"
    CAM_ADDR       = ":5000"
    PACKET         = 60000
)

type msg struct {
    Fragment     bool
    FragmentID   int
    LastFragment bool
    Data         []byte
}

type reporting struct {
    Fps       int
    Size      int
    Fragments float64
    Encoding  time.Duration
    Writing   time.Duration
}

func main() {
    conn, err := udpDial()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var stderr bytes.Buffer

    //bash script with commands for interfacing with the camera.
    //script outputs to stdout.
    cmd := exec.Command("./v4l2")
    pipe, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    defer pipe.Close()
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    }

    //pizero - has issues serializing.
    buffer := make(chan [][]byte, 500)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var statistic reporting
    wg.Add(3)

    go func() {
        //used for statistics
        var fps int
        start := time.Now()

        for {
            fps++
            if time.Since(start) >= time.Second {
                statistic.Fps = fps
                fps = 0
                //reset timer
                start = time.Now()
            }

            frame := make([]byte, 80000)
            n, err := pipe.Read(frame)
            if err != nil {
                pipe.Close()
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            frame = frame[0:n]

            statistic.Size = len(frame)

            go processFrame(frame, buffer, &statistic)
        }
    }()

    //
    go func() {
        for {
            //time how long it takes pi0 to serialize
            start := time.Now()
            fragments := <-buffer
            for _, fragment := range fragments {
                _, err := conn.Write(fragment)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                }
            }
            statistic.Writing = time.Since(start)
        }

    }()

    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
        for _ = range ticker.C {
            fmt.Printf("\r%vfps, fsize: %v, fragments: %v, enctime: %v, writetime: %v, bufsize: %v ", statistic.Fps, statistic.Size, statistic.Fragments, statistic.Encoding, statistic.Writing, len(buffer))
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}

func processFrame(frame []byte, buffer chan<- [][]byte, statistic *reporting) {
    start := time.Now()
    f := msg{}

    //UDP single packet size 65507 bytes.
    //Func implements frame fragmentation.
    //Frames bigger than the UDP packet size limit will be split.

    //Fragment -  indicates if the message sent to the server is fragmented.
    //LastFragment - set to true when sending the last fragment to the server.
    //FragmentID - fragment identifier.

    //UDP does not guarantee arrival of the packet. FragmentID is needed by the server
    //in order to identify if the received message is part of a fragment and if it belongs
    //to the fragmented message received.

    //On mismatch the server will drop fragments it currently has in memory.

    length := len(frame)

    if length < PACKET {
        f.Fragment = false
        f.FragmentID = 1
        f.LastFragment = true
        f.Data = frame

        fragment, err := bson.Marshal(f)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        statistic.Encoding = time.Since(start)

        packet := [][]byte{fragment}

        buffer <- packet
        return
    }

    //Find out in how many pieces the frame must be split
    pieces := float64(length) / float64(PACKET)
    //Returns the floating point remainder(if any).
    //`pieces` is often not a whole number
    r := math.Remainder(float64(length), float64(PACKET))
    remainder := int(r)
    //Number of pieces that fit the defined packet constant
    fragments := int(math.Floor(pieces))
    statistic.Fragments = pieces

    /*
        fmt.Println("Pieces: ", pieces)
        fmt.Println("Remainder: ", remainder)
        fmt.Println("Fragments: ", fragments)
        fmt.Println("Bytes: ", length)
    */

    //remainder can be a negative number
    //find out the positive remainder
    //remainder must be always positive
    //used for byte reslicing
    if remainder < 0 {
        remainder = PACKET + remainder //remainder here is a negative num
    }

    //default values
    id := 1
    beginning := 0
    end := remainder
    last := false

    //fragment storage. a go routine will loop over it and write to server
    packet := make([][]byte, int(math.Ceil(pieces)))

    for i := 0; fragments >= 0; i++ {
        f.Fragment = true
        f.FragmentID = id
        f.LastFragment = last
        f.Data = frame[beginning:end]

        fragment, err := bson.Marshal(f)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        packet[i] = fragment
        /*
            fmt.Printf("Start:%v, End:%v, Data length:%v,Packet length %v\n", start, end, len(f.Data), len(packet))
            fmt.Printf("Data length:%v,Packet length %v\n", len(f.Data), len(packet))
        */

        fragments--
        beginning = end
        end = beginning + PACKET

        if fragments == 0 {
            last = true
        }

        id++
    }
    buffer <- packet
    statistic.Encoding = time.Since(start)
}

func udpDial() (*net.UDPConn, error) {
    encAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", FFMPEG_ENCODER)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    locAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", CAM_ADDR)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", locAddr, encAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}
```

Server:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync"

    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

const (
    CONN_HOST = "192.168.178.200"
    CONN_PORT = "8000"
    CONN_TYPE = "udp"
)

type msg struct {
    Fragment     bool
    FragmentID   int
    LastFragment bool
    Data         []byte
}

func main() {
    logfile := "log.txt"
    logger, err := os.Create(logfile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    log.SetOutput(logger)
    defer logger.Close()

    ladr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    listen, err := net.ListenUDP(CONN_TYPE, ladr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer listen.Close()

    fmt.Println("Listening on " + CONN_HOST + ":" + CONN_PORT)

    collector := [][]byte{}

    var fragmentID int
    var expectedID int
    expectedID = 1

    buffer := make(chan msg, 1000)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        for {
            buf := make([]byte, 65507)
            n, _, err := listen.ReadFromUDP(buf)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }

            if len(buf[0:n]) > 0 {
                f := msg{}

                err = bson.Unmarshal(buf[0:n], &f)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                buffer <- f
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            f := <-buffer
            //log.Printf("fragment :%v, fragId: %v, expectedID: %v, lastFragment: %v\n", f.Fragment, f.FragmentID, expectedID, f.LastFragment)
            //fmt.Printf("Data: %v\n", len(f.Data))
            if !f.Fragment {
                _, err = os.Stdout.Write(f.Data)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
                continue
            }

            if f.Fragment && !f.LastFragment {

                fragmentID = f.FragmentID

                if fragmentID == expectedID {
                    collector = append(collector, f.Data)
                    expectedID++
                    continue
                }
                log.Println("INCOMPLETE FRAME")
            }

            if f.Fragment && f.LastFragment {

                fragmentID = f.FragmentID

                if fragmentID == expectedID {
                    collector = append(collector, f.Data)

                    frame := bytes.Join(collector, []byte(""))

                    _, err = os.Stdout.Write(frame)
                    if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                    }

                    //fmt.Println("Bytes: ", len(frame))

                    expectedID = 1
                    collector = collector[:0]

                    continue
                }
                log.Println("INCOMPLETE FRAME")

            }
            expectedID = 1
            collector = collector[:0]
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Readability

To ease the readability (and testability) of your code, I would recommend you to split it in multiple functions communicating via multiple channels.

For instance, for the client:

```
func getOutput(command string) (io.ReadCloser, error)        // to launch the v4l2
func readFrames(in io.ReadCloser, out <-chan Frame)
func splitFrames(in chan<- Frame, out <-chan Fragment)
func sendFragments(in <-chan Fragment)
```

Your `main` would then consist of creating the different channels and launching those functions as goroutines (except for `getOutput`).

With this approach, you will need a fixed amount of goroutines (instead of starting a new one for each frame: `go processFrame(frame, buffer, &statistic)`,
 which might qualify as "*I shot myself in the foot*").

### Statistics

Regarding the statistics, if see multiple possibilities:

- pass the object as a variable (current usage)
- or make it a global variable
- or make it a channel of `Report` (the signification of `Value` depends on the `Operation`):

-

```
type Report struct {
    Operation string
    Value     int
    Duration  time.Duration
}
```

### Performance

If you need to make your code faster, you will need to identify the bottlenecks. For this, I recommend you to profile your code : https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

- Add the code `var cpuprofile = flag.String("cpuprofile", "", "write cpu profile to file")...`
- transfer the `*.profile` file to your computer
- analyze the function calls